# Why isn't there hydrofluoric acid in fluoridated water?

Tags: halides, water-treatment, salt

From what I've read, when water is fluoridated it's done so either by $\ce{NaF}$ artificially or $\ce{CaF2}$ naturally. If this is correct, shouldn't the reaction $\ce{CaF2 + H2O -> CaO + 2HF}$ occur? Does something else in the water just react more readily?

Comment: No, it can never occur. Tap water cannot or will not contain free hydrofluoric acid.

Comment: Fluoride ion is only present at about 1 part per million. Not much higher can lead to mottling of teeth. And CaO cannot be in water: it reacts vigorously with water, producing calcium hydroxide. So the solution is very dilute and hydrofluoric acid would be almost entirely dissociated, meaning it would be present in negligible concentrations.

Comment: @EdV I see, so because CaO would immediately react with water, form Ca(OH)2 which would in turn react with HF to form CaF2 again and overall this just amounts to basically nothing happening? Or does it not even manage to form the CaO in the first place?

Comment: Calcium fluoride is an ionic compound that has low solubility in water, so what little dissolves just gives calcium and fluoride ions.

Comment: Generally speaking, if you have a chain of reactions that amounts to nothing happening, it just doesn't happen in the first place. It is as simple as that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your proposed reaction is unlikely**

That is because the combination $\ce{CaF2 + H2O}$ (under tap water conditions) is much more stable than $\ce{CaO + 2 HF}$. In other words, the electronic energy of the former is lower and the system preferably stays in this state. That does not mean, however, that the reaction does not occur! It just means that the concentration of the products is incredibly small and probably you would not be able to detect them at all.
Because of this, chemists tend to say that it does not take place, although that is technically incorrect.

**HF does occur, but in tiny concentrations.**

I think there is a more likely way how HF would form.
Let us look at the reactions that are necessary to have $\ce{HF}$ in the fluoridated water.
The first step is the solvation of the solid fluoride ($\ce{NaF}$ or $\ce{CaF2}$) in water: $\ce{NaF2(s) <=> Na+(aq) + F-(aq)}$ or $\ce{CaF2(s) <=> Ca+(aq) + 2 F-(aq)}$, respectively. Sodium and calcium ions are stable in aqueous solution, so we can neglect them in the next steps. Just imagine that they are still in the water, surrounded by water molecules.
The second and last step is the fluoride ion reaction with water. [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluoride#Basicity), the reaction $\ce{F- + H2O <=> HF + OH-}$ has a $pK_b$ value of 10.8. This means:
$$ pK_b = -lg(K_b) \Rightarrow K_b = 10^{-pK_b} $$
$$ K_b = \frac{[\ce{HF}] \cdot [\ce{OH-}]}{[\ce{F-}]} = 10^{-10.8}$$

So here we can see that in a solution containing only fluoride ions and inert counterions, the portion of hydrofluoric acid is incredibly low! As mentioned above, you would probably not be able to detect it.

**Cunningham**

Cunningham's Law worked here for me in the comments.

> Generally speaking, if you have a chain of reactions that amounts to nothing happening, it just doesn't happen in the first place. It is as simple as that.

That is a severe misunderstanding of chemical reaction dynamics. In fact, the exact opposite is true: If you have a chain of reactions, all of them happen! The question is only to which extent, which I tried to answer above.
See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_equilibrium) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_equilibrium) for more details.

Comment: Are you sure $\ce{[H2O]}$ enters the formula for the $K_b$?

Comment: Your doubt was justified, I looked it up and it doesn't. Thanks, I edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: The point is that is not occurrence at a microscopic level that we are looking for, but outcome. I think that Neretin comment is appropriate, in this thread.